# How to prototype a new concept for UI design for mobile devices?

Tags: gui-design, android

I am currently developing a new kind of UI for android device and I wanted to know how do I make prototype of it ? since none of the existing UI design tool has support for it. I wanted to include different gestures and movements and just about everything different.

Comment: Hi Jimit, welcome to UX.se! This is not a good place to ask which tools you should be using. Look into something like http://proto.io/ and other tools for mobile interactions.

Comment: Why are there no tools with support for it? There is still a user interface and interactions, which you can describe. There is even an notation for gesture interactions and movements (http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1071)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Tony mentioned, pencil and paper is always the best place to start. It’s a great way to sketch ideas, edit and refine quickly and also generate feedback by literally walking around to other designers or stakeholders to get their feedback.

There are lots of websites, articles and books on the art of paper prototyping that you may find interesting. If you have this method sorted and are purely after recommendations for software applications, I would try to use a fairly flexible wire framing/prototyping program such as Axure (which is just one of many). Jumping straight into HTML/CSS can be time consuming if you aren’t a front-end developer and some programs will let you add in JavaScript actions through a no coding needed interface, which can save lots of time.

In my experience, a program that also lets you adjust the ‘sketchiness’ of the look and feel is always a big plus. This really helps when showing your user interface designs or interaction patterns to clients or stakeholders who would usually nitpick colours, type and image choice. My tip is to keep your prototype as ‘low-fidelity’ as possible until you move on to the visual design phase. I may be telling you something you already know and there are many applications that will let you adequately prototype your bespoke gestures and interactions, but the most important factor here is getting the workflow and design process right. Define, design, refine.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, pencil and paper. This is fast and cheap as well. Most solutions that will allow you to build interactive wire frames will have pre-built widgets. Thus, they won't fit your bespoke design. Pencil and paper is your best solution then moving onto HTML would be the next easiest. From there you can validate the concept and decide if you want to build a native app.